# A vino nuevo, odres nuevos

Tags: modismos, context

I saw this Biblical expression used in [El País](https://elpais.com/eps/2024-01-02/hay-un-cura-que-lo-hace-todo-en-espana.html?sma=newsletter_correosideseado&utm_medium=email&utm_source=newsletter&utm_campaign=correosideseado_2024.01.08_3). A priest is speaking about change in one shape or another.

I searched in online dictionaries. "Odres" are wineskins according to the RAE and Spanishdict.
Spanishdict provided the only online modern reference to it:
"la reformación no fue vino nuevo, odres nuevos". However, I can't find the exact link.
I understand it means something along the lines of "new wine needs new wineskins", so I suppose sweeping new changes are needed.

My question is: is the expression purely Biblical or like other Biblical phrases can it be transferred to everyday and modern life? I mean, today, in modern Spain and Latin America, would it be understood and used?

I am not aware of this line being used in English. Other Biblical or Gospel lines are used however, e.g. "The harvest is rich but the labourers are few".

Comment: Have you done a search for "New wine in old bottles" as an English phrase?

Comment: Yes, I have just read about it in English.I believe I have heard it vaguely.However, my question remains as to its modern usage and if easily understood nowadays particularly in Spain. Also, could you provide some modern context in a non-religious sense, if it is used that way in modern times?

Comment: It's from the Bible, yes: https://www.biblegateway.com/passage/?search=Luke%205%3A37-39&version=NKJV **And no one puts new wine into old wineskins; or else the new wine will burst the wineskins and be spilled, and the wineskins will be ruined**. 38 But new wine must be put into new wineskins,//The translation does say new.

Comment: There's all sorts of Bible stuff that is not necessarily aphoristic in the same way in different places.

Answer (score 0):

Salvo casos particulares, las expresiones bíblicas no son usadas en una conversación casual y mundana. Eso no quiere decir que no las puedas usar, sólo que no tenés que abusar de ellas. Al introducirlas en su adecuada medida, vas a hacerte ver más culto. Un ejemplo claro de esto lo hallamos en el prestigioso economista y actual presidente argentino, Javier Milei:

> Recuerdo cuando hace dos años junto a la doctora Villaruel, hoy vicepresidente de la Nación, recuerdo que en una entrevista me habían dicho: ‘Pero si son 2 entre 257, no van a lograr nada!’. Y recuerdo que en ese día mi respuesta fue una cita del libro de Macabeos (3:19), que dice que **la victoria en el campo de batalla no depende de la cantidad de soldados, sino de las fuerzas que vienen del cielo**.([discurso de asunción](https://youtu.be/jySRdtIemLU?feature=shared&t=1936))

Por lo tanto, es excéntrico pero no está mal y podés llegar muy lejos revitalizando algún pasaje bíblico que había quedado en el olvido.

Comment: Gracias por su explicación interesante .Nunca he oído de esa expresión tampoco. Creo que el uso es igual que el inglés-se pusede usarlo pero para ser culto y depende del ámbito y el contexto. En mi primera expresión se puede usarla para un cambio cualquiera ,no solo sistemático? @tac